# Array[] form validation

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, forms

`array.length` keeps outputing 2007 arrays?

hmm.. I have a table which has of course 2 `<tr>` 1 for header and 1 for the values from the database

my table has a columns called code and description where ids are `fCode[]` and `fDesc[]` and each has an element

I have a code where I can clone a table row every time I click add. In every added row adds another `fCode[]` and `fDesc[]`.

`2 rows = 2 fCode[], fDesc[]`

At my javascript function I have this

```
function validate_pr_form(e) {

    var fCode = document.forms[e].elements["fCode[]"];
    var fDesc = document.forms[e].elements["fDesc[]"];
    for ( i = 0; i < fCode.length; i++ ){
        if ( fCode[i].value == "" ) {
            alert("Please choose product code");
            fCode[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < fDesc.length; i++ ){
        if ( fDesc[i].value == "" ) {
            alert("Please choose product description");
            fDesc[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    e.submit();

}
```

Whenever I load the page and hit submit button, I always get 2007 arrays but when I add another row, so it becomes 2 rows now (2 `fCode[]` and 2 `fDesc[]`) I get 2 arrays and those focuses in each array index normally.

My problem only goes with 1 row...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the answer but I've already solved my problem by getting element's name like this

```
fCode = document.getElementsByName("fCode[]");

for ( var i = 0; i < fCode.length; i++ ){
        if ( fCode[i].value == "" ) {
            alert("Please choose 'Product Code'.");
            fCode[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fCode = document.forms[e].elements["fCode[]"];
if (typeof fCode.length != "number")
   fCode = [fCode];
var fDesc = document.forms[e].elements["fDesc[]"];
if (typeof fDesc.length != "number")
   fDesc = [fDesc];
```